# Rake preview not loading the page at localhost

Tags: ruby, rake, rvm, blogs, octopress

- I have a [Octopress](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/) blog on Github
- I use Mac terminal to do my changes and push blog.
- Everything was fine until I upgraded to Mountain Lion.
- Now when I do the following

> ```
> >     $ rake preview
> >     /Users/hhimanshu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197:
> > warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode
> > 040777
> >     Starting to watch source with Jekyll and Compass. Starting Rack on port 4000
> >     /Users/hhimanshu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197:
> > warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode
> > 040777
> >     /Users/hhimanshu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197:
> > warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode
> > 040777
> >     /Users/hhimanshu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197:
> > warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode
> > 040777
> >     /Users/hhimanshu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/input/parse_doc.rb:22:in
> > `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use
> > String#encode instead.
> >     Configuration from /Users/hhimanshu/code/p/python/blog/octopress/_config.yml
> >     [2012-10-02 13:49:23] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
> >     [2012-10-02 13:49:23] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-02-16) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
> >     [2012-10-02 13:49:23] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=75477 port=4000
> >     Auto-regenerating enabled: source -> public
> >     [2012-10-02 13:49:24] regeneration: 94 files changed
> >     
> >     Dear developers making use of FSSM in your projects,
> >     FSSM is essentially dead at this point. Further development will
> >     be taking place in the new shared guard/listen project. Please
> >     let us know if you need help transitioning! ^_^b
> >     - Travis Tilley
> >     
> >     >>> Compass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
> ```

It just keeps there on the terminal, and when I hit localhost:4000 , the page hangs forever

What is that might be causing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Propably your XCode was upgraded too and you have to downgrade it.